# Toggle Breakpoint in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I try to toggle breakpoint and debug my program in Eclipse. I got the error like this: `Failed to connect to VM connection. Timed out.` Any solutions for this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting eclipse? Also, kill `adb` from Task Manager (Windows) and restart eclipse.

Comment: I tried this but not working

Comment: Is your JDK working properly?